# How to push into an array and not reset index PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have and array and i need to push a value into the first index(0).

```
array:3 [▼
  4 => "test1"
  5 => "test2"
  6 => "test3"
]
```

I need the indexes to stay like this, so the array will become like below. Since the indexes are the IDS of the values.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "None selected"
  4 => "test1"
  5 => "test2"
  6 => "test3"
]
```

To populate array:

```
$accuGroups = UpselGroup::where('accu_group','1')->with('UpselProducts.products')->pluck('naam','id')->toArray();
```

What i tried:

```
$accuGroups = array_merge([0 => 'None selected'], $accuGroups);
```

outcome (not what i want):

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "None selected"
  1 => "test1"
  2 => "test2"
  3 => "test3"
]
```

Any help is appreciated

thanks

Comment: array_values($array ) to reset the key

Comment: I do not wish to reset the key

Comment: $accuGroups[0]="None selected"; try this

Comment: array_merge() function, and the keys are integers, the function returns a new array with integer keys starting at 0 and increases by 1 for each value

Comment: Every time you manipulate an array the index will change. What you can do is create your count function to ignore certain indexes like the 0 that you wanted above.

Comment: try my answer below @JordyGroote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array_merge() function, and the keys are integers, the function returns a new array with integer keys starting at 0 and increases by 1 for each value

so use like this :

```
$accuGroups[0]="None selected";
```

Comment: This suits my needs. Thank you for this. I will approve the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: glad to help you . if my answer is useful mark it with green tick its's useful for future user reference @JordyGroote

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$none_selected = array(
        0 => 'None selected');

    $accuGroups = $none_selected + $accuGroups;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<?php
    $queue = array("test1", "test2","test3", "test4");
    array_unshift($queue, "None selected");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($queue);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$accuGroups[0]="Not Selected.";
$accuGroups[6]="Not Selected.";
```

The array will reset its index value with given Value;

Answer (score 0):

Keep another value which you have to merge as array and add it to first array and you will get result.

```
$a=['4' => "test1", '5' => "test2",'6' => "test3"];
$b=['0'=>'Not Selected'];
$c=$b+$a;
```

in $c you will get result as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
    $array = array('4' => 'test1','5' => 'test2', '6' => 'test3');
    $add = array('0'=>'None selected');
    $final =  $add + $array;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($final);die;
?>
```